# TikZ intersection problem with PWM signal generation

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

Consider the MWE of a PWM signal generation based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255081/creating-a-pulse-width-modulator-in-tikz) question.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\step}{.25}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw [->] (0,-1.4) -- ++(8,0) node [right] {$t$};
    \draw [->] (0,-1.4) node [left] {$0$} -- ++(0,3) ;
    \draw [name path=sawtooth, line width=0.1pt,line join=miter] 
      \foreach \x in {0,\step,...,6} {
        % (\x,1.0) -- ++(0,-2.0) -- ++(\step,2.0) % y domain = -1.0 -- 1.0
        (\x,1.4) -- ++(0,-2.8) -- ++(\step,2.8) % y domain = -1.4 -- 1.4
      };

      \draw [red,smooth, domain=0:2*pi, name path global=wave-1,line width=0.1pt] plot ({\x},{sin((\x+0) r)}) node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$sig_1$};
      \draw [blue,name intersections={of={wave-1} and sawtooth, total=\n}]
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,\n} {
         \ifodd\i {}
          \else
            (intersection-\lasti |- 0,-2*1) rectangle (intersection-\i |- 0,-3)  
          \fi
        };
      \draw [->] (0,-3) -- ++(8,0) node [right] {$t$};
      \draw [->] (0,-3) node [left] {0} -- ++(0,1.2) ;      

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This MWE compiles correct and the generated PWM signal is also correct. Of course, I want the sawtooth signal to be in the y domain (-1.0,1.0) so that the PWM signal is maximal and minimal. But if I
compile the MWE with that y domain, Tikz fails to determine the intersections correctly. I made the sawtooth and sine wave with ultra thin lines but no success.
Can someone shed a light on the capabilities of the determination of the intersections in this particular case?

Comment: Does it help increasing the number of points via `samples=301` in the plot? Line width doesn't matter for intersection computations. You are trying to intersect with the miter of the line, intersections are not that sensitive.

Comment: @percusse Sorry, no. But if I use `\newcommand{\step}{.5}` then I can decrease the y domain to (-1.2 -- 1.2)

Comment: Then draw a dummy saw tooth but use a `\path` that is not drawn for the intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the red signal is very close to the outer ends of the sawtooth signal at an intersection, Ti*k*Z finds only one instead of two intersections. Therefore, you may want to split the sawtooth path into two, a vertical and a diagonal one. (BTW, it is sometimes safer to work with "fake straight lines" when one wants to sort intersections, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418650/121799).)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\step}{.25}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw [->] (0,-1.4) -- ++(8,0) node [right] {$t$};
    \draw [->] (0,-1.4) node [left] {$0$} -- ++(0,3) ;
    \draw [name path=sawtooth vert, line width=0.1pt,line join=miter] 
      \foreach \x in {0,\step,...,6} {
        (\x,1.0) to[bend left=0] ++(0,-2.0)  % y domain = -1.0 -- 1.0
        %(\x,1.4) -- ++(0,-2.8) -- ++(\step,2.8) % y domain = -1.4 -- 1.4
      };
     \draw [name path=sawtooth diag, line width=0.1pt,line join=miter]   
      \foreach \x in {0,\step,...,6} {
       (\x,-1.0) to[bend left=0] ++(\step,2.0)};
      \draw [red,smooth, domain=0:2*pi, name path global=wave-1,line width=0.1pt] plot ({\x},{sin((\x+0) r)}) node [below right, font=\scriptsize] {$sig_1$};
      \path  [name intersections={of={wave-1} and {sawtooth diag}, name=x, total=\n}]
         \pgfextra{\typeout{\n\space intersections\space in\space vert}};
      \draw [blue,name intersections={of={wave-1} and {sawtooth vert}, total=\n}]
      \pgfextra{\typeout{\n\space intersections}}
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,\n} {
%          \ifodd\i {}
%           \else
            (x-\lasti |- 0,-2*1) rectangle (intersection-\i |- 0,-3)  
%          \fi
        };
      \draw [->] (0,-3) -- ++(8,0) node [right] {$t$};
      \draw [->] (0,-3) node [left] {0} -- ++(0,1.2) ;      

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is almost what I needed. I only need that the PWM signal is high when the sine wave is greater than the sawtooth. I tried to switch vert and diag, intersection and x, but to no success. Could you adapt your answer please.

Comment: never mind, I succeeded. Changed diag and vert in the plotting routine, deleted remembering `\last`, changed `foreach` range from 1 to \n, draw rectange from `x-\i` to `\intersection-i`...

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw OK, cool, sorry, I was doing other things... ;-)

Comment: I find it amazing how fast some responses are posted. Just a few hours ago I found and answer to a relatively simple question and someone beat me by 18 seconds...

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Well, yesterday I was beaten by 7 seconds, and some other day I beat someone by 2.....